# Sticky Footer and IE

Tags: css, html, footer

I am having an issue whereby when my  contains a floating element my sticky footer does not stick to the bottom it will sit at the end of the non floated content.

My Aim is to have the FOOTER at the bottom of the page window if page content does not fill an entire page, and at the BOTTOM of the page CONTENT when content overflows a single page height.

Here is my code:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sticky.css"/>
    <title>Sticky Footer Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
    <div id="wrap">
        <p class="navbargreen">Green Navigation Bar</p>
    </div>
</nav>

<main>
    <div id="wrap">
        <p class="redtext">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <div id="box1">Floater 1</div>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>footer</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

---

```
Here is my CSS:

html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}

main {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0;
background-color: yellow;
}

.navbargreen {
height: 30px;
width: 960px;
background-color: greenyellow;
}

.redtext {
background-color: red;
height: 3000px;
}

#box1 {
float: left;
height: 400px;
width: 300px;
background-color: orange;
}

footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: purple;
}
```

---

This is driving me mad!

I have googled searched and experimented galore with this mockup test page but blow me down I CANNOT solve it :-(

I know it has something to do with floats but I cannot work this out!

Comment: Which version(s) of IE in particular?

Comment: Have you had any luck Blake?

Comment: No, sorry.. I haven't had a chance to test anything (I don't have a good IE test environment handy most of the time). At a guess, I'd say you should put `min-height: 100%;` on both the `html` and the `body` (as the `body` is the direct parent of the absolutely positioned element), but that's about all I can say at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for input I really appreciate it :-) will try the min-height and let you know thanks again buddy

Answer (score 0):

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/czgoxafr/27/

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -70px; 
}
.wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .wrap:after {
  height: 70px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly!

Comment: What this has done though is stuck the footer at the bottom of the window at all times. 

I need it to stick at the bottom of the content if content spills over more than a single page height, and stick to the bottom of the window if the content doesn't fill a complete window.

What it must not do though is sit ontop of or over content :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: It shows at all times regardless of page height.

I need it to 1.  Show at the bottom of the page if content does not fill an entire window height 2. Sit at the very bottom of page CONTENT if page content flows over more than a single window height.  At present it sits at the bottom regardless of content height

Comment: Wrap is an undefined height though across all pages so it needs to be set to height: auto to enable it to resize accordingly to content height

Comment: This sticky footer works in chrome and Firefox just not in IE

Comment: I'm sorry it isnt working!  The sticky footer is at the bottom of the window not at the bottom of the page content, but thank you for trying I do appreciate it

Comment: It's static development on my local machine using the CSS and HTML as pasted above.  It works on Chrome and Firefoz and Safari but not on IE 11

Comment: please open above in internet explorer to see what happens